startingTimestamp option when using Spark with Kafka
I am curious about the
startingTimestamp

key option.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html
How does it work behind the scenes?
Does Spark load all the events into memory and then filter them out by the timestamp of the event, or does Kafka know how to filter out all the events using the partitions' metadata? Since events with varying timestamps can exist across different partitions, how does Kafka know how to filter them out?
This becomes crucial in terms of loading all of the data into memory, instead of letting the source handle the job, which could potentially be faster and more optimized.

Loading and filtering the entire topic in memory isn't needed, only one record batch would need scanned once the index containing the requested offset is found from the log segments on disk.
Given a mapping of topic partition and some timestamp, the KafkaConsumer can use offsetsForTimes to lookup offsets to start consuming from.

The returned offset for each partition is the earliest offset whose timestamp is greater than or equal to the given timestamp in the corresponding partition.


but how is looking for the corresponding timestamp? using binary search? this is what i am curious about

I've never looked into it. This article seems to say it does https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-kafka/timestamp-based-lookup-apache-kafka/read
